# Why can't I add graticule to my polar stereo map? (OpenLayers 4)

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I'm working on a map in OpenLayers 4 with projection EPSG:32661

This is the JavaScript, which targets a #map div on the page:

```
proj4.defs('EPSG:32661', '+proj=stere +lat_0=90 +lon_0=0 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 
+a=3396190 +b=3376200 +units=m +no_defs');
var north_stereo = ol.proj.get('EPSG:32661');
north_stereo.setExtent([-2357032, -2357032, 2357032, 2357032]);
var npoleURL = "https://planetarymaps.usgs.gov/cgi-bin/mapserv? 
map=/maps/mars/mars_npole.map";

var np = new ol.layer.Tile({
    title: 'North Pole',
    source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
        url: npoleURL,
        params: {LAYERS: 'MOLA_color_north'}
    }),
    projection: north_stereo,
});

var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [
        np
    ],
target: 'map',
view: new ol.View({
    projection: north_stereo,
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 4
  })
});
var graticule = new ol.Graticule({
    strokeStyle: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.8)',
        width: 1,
    }),
});
graticule.setMap(map);
```

[This CodePen](https://codepen.io/jangell/pen/jKVjbo) demonstrates the problem I'm having. Commenting out the final line, which is the line that attaches the graticule to the map, causes the map to render normally. Running the code with that line in causes the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null
at Object.ol.extent.applyTransform (ol-debug.js:4719)
at Object.ol.proj.transformExtent (ol-debug.js:6268)
at ol.Graticule.updateProjectionInfo_ (ol-debug.js:57921)
at ol.Graticule.handlePostCompose_ (ol-debug.js:57876)
at ol.Map.boundListener (ol-debug.js:7277)
at ol.Map.ol.events.EventTarget.dispatchEvent (ol-debug.js:7697)
at ol.renderer.canvas.Map.dispatchComposeEvent_ (ol-debug.js:26392)
at ol.renderer.canvas.Map.renderFrame (ol-debug.js:26480)
at ol.Map.ol.PluggableMap.renderFrame_ (ol-debug.js:18709)
at ol.Map.<anonymous> (ol-debug.js:17624)
```

It's my understanding that proj4 automatically generates the transformation functions. Transforming points or feature layers has been successful, so as far as I can tell, the graticule is the only thing causing trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is caused because there is no worldExtent defined, setting this should resolve the issue

```
north_stereo.setWorldExtent([...]);
```

Comment: This got graticule to appear on the polar projections! It still doesn't work perfectly - when I move the view, for example, it changes the graticule line lengths, which should extent over the entire viewport and presently don't, but that's likely some tweaks that I need to figure out on my end, and I'll update with another comment when I figure it out for anyone who finds this in the future.